# Provide Android with fake speed (e.g. Vehicle)

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I need to fake the speed of the movement of the phone in the vehicle - (no accelerometer).

I need to be able to press the button on the phone "Start Engine" , "Stop Engine" and then "Speed up", "Speed down" somewhere in between.

I'm new to Android so any help will be much appreciated. 
Cheers

EDIT:

I mean UI Buttons. 
I need to tell phone it is moving even though it is not. 
So something like maybe send fake GPS coordinates in a loop or something??? But then how do I change speed.

Comment: If you aren't using the accelerometer...then what *are* you using?

Comment: In the real world, you cannot really use accelerometer in a vehicle and expect it to notice you're moving and how fast. For now I only need to lie about it and tell it it's moving even though it's not. Should I just simply provide fake speed ? Maybe I'm just overcomplicating things ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about **physical buttons** that you could actually press, then you could use a **BroadcastReceiver** which has a filter of **android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION** to do whatever you want when pressing keys. However, I don't think you could manage that much actions with just volume up and down. If you're talking about buttons on UI, then just put the button on UI and use **OnClickListener of each button** to do what you want.

Comment: The more you tell, the more we could help